Python Scrapy 429 Unknown Status
I'm trying to scraping web site with scrapy on pythonanywhere. I'm Scheduled the task to run specific time in daily. I have run_spider.py and run_spider.sh files for pythonanywhere. And pythonanywhere using run_spider.sh to run. But I'm receiving 429 Unknown Status when the scheduled time is come.
Additional TraceBack: 2024-08-05 16:01:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET examplewebsite.com> (failed 1 times): 429 Unknown Status
And when I'm running manually like scrapy crawl fetch_stock is running perfect no error or other things.
My settings.py file configuration is like this:
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# settings.py
# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32
# CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 10  # Lower delay
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 3
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 3
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 3
# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
# COOKIES_ENABLED = False
# COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
# TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False
# TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
# DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
# DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
#    "Accept-Language": "en",
# }
# }

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
# SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
# SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    "snake.middlewares.SnakeSpiderMiddleware": 543,
# }
# }

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
# DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    "snake.middlewares.SnakeDownloaderMiddleware": 543,
# }
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    "fetch_stock.middlewares.FetchStockSpiderMiddleware": 543,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
# EXTENSIONS = {
# EXTENSIONS = {
#    "scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole": None,
# }
# }

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
# ITEM_PIPELINES = {
# ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    "snake.pipelines.SnakePipeline": 300,
# }
# }

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
# AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
# AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
# AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
# AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
# AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False
AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
# HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
# HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
# HTTPCACHE_DIR = "httpcache"
# HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
# HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = "scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage"
# HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
# HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
# HTTPCACHE_DIR = "httpcache"
# HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
# HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = "scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage"

# Set settings whose default value is deprecated to a future-proof value
REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION = "2.7"

TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"

My run_spider.py file (this file contains which is the same location with scrapy.cfg:
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from fetch_stock.spiders.besled import StockSpider


process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(StockSpider)
process.start()


My run_spider.sh file (this file contains which is the same location with scrapy.cfg):
#!/bin/bash
python3.10 /home/zephyrus/shopify_fetch_stock/fetch_stock/run_spider.py


429 typically means too many requests. There are many previous questions about how to avoid that (scrape less, or less frequently; or spread the load over multiple clients; or agree with the hosting site on a different arrangement)

A 429 status code typically indicates that there are too many requests being sent. To avoid this, you might consider using proxies to crawl the site. Alternatively, you can reduce the number of concurrent requests to prevent this issue.
